# Android NullPointerException - Spinner onItemSelected `view` parameter is null after rotating

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

**Note: A limiting workaround from [another, similar SO question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20860679/2423194) worked for me, but I am interested in finding a true solution.** The workaround was to add this to my Activity:

```
@Override  
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) { /* do nothing */ }
```

But I would still like to leave this question open in hopes for finding a better solution.

---

My app crashes when it rotates on the latest Android (Marshmallow, Lollipop), but it works on KitKat. In the Spinner onClick method, I get the first child of the parent, which is the first textview in the dropdown list (aka spinner). It works just fine when I do not rotate it. Also, when I comment-out that line that throws the NullPointerException, it works just fine too. So that is the only cause of the problem.

**I know it is Null, but I don't understand why, or how to fix it? Also, please note that I cannot use XML for this, because the text color is only known dynamically at runtime. Also, I want the minimum API to be 15.**

I added some debug code, and found out that before rotating, `parent` and `view` parameters are both not null. But after rotating, `view` is null. (But `parent` is still not null).

See ****** by the line that has the null pointer exception:

```
private void setUpSpinner(int accentColor, final int backgroundColor, Toolbar toolbar)
{
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    //Get rid of the normal toolbar's title, because the spinner is replacing the title.
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    //Set the choices on the spinner by setting the adapter.
    spinner.setAdapter(new SpinnerAdapter(toolbar.getContext(), new String[]{"Overview", "Story", "Specifications", "Poll", "Video"},
            accentColor, backgroundColor));

    //Set the listener for when each option is clicked.
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            Log.e("ITEM SELECTED", "SPINNER" + Integer.toString(position));

            //This is necessary to set the color of the "action bar title." (Really, this is just
            //changing the text color of the spinner when it is at rest; or changing the selected
            //option's color.)
 ****************((TextView) view).setTextColor(backgroundColor);

            //Change the contents of the DealPage depending on what option was selected in the spinner.
           // CODE OMITTED
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
        {
        }
    });
}
```

spinner_item.xml:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@android:id/text1"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
          android:gravity="center_vertical"
          android:padding="5dp"
          android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"/>
```

OnCreate method:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        context = this;
        RealmDatabase.setRealmInstance(this);

        //----------- UNPACK EXTRAS -----------
        String date = getIntent().getExtras().getString(KeyStrings.EXTRA_DATE);

        //---------------- PREREQUISITE INITIALIZATION ----------
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_deal_page);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_with_spinner);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        //------------ Enable "UP" navigation ---------------
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        getDataFromDatabase(date);

        //----------------- THEMES AND COLORS ------------------

        //Set up colors
        final int backgroundColor = this.deal.getTheme().getBackgroundColor().getColor();
        final int accentColor = this.deal.getTheme().getAccentColor().getColor();
        String themeForeground = this.deal.getTheme().getForeground();
        final int foreground = generateForegroundColor(themeForeground);
        final String foregroundWebView = generateForegroundWebViewString(themeForeground); // This is necessary because HTML does not have an alpha channel.

        //Set toolbar colors
        toolbar.setBackgroundColor(accentColor);
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(backgroundColor);

        //Set Page Background Color
        RelativeLayout dealPageBackground = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.deal_page_background);
        dealPageBackground.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);

        //----------- INITIALIZE THE ACTUAL DEAL PAGE STUFF ----------------

        //Title
        TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
        title.setText(this.deal.getTitle());
        title.setTextColor(foreground);

        //Price
        TextView price = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.price);
        NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        price.setText(fmt.format(this.deal.getItems().first().getPrice()));
        price.setTextColor(foreground);

        //ViewInBrowser
        setUpViewInBrowserButton(backgroundColor, accentColor);

        AndDown andDown = new AndDown();

        //Set up "linkColorHTML"
        String linkColorHTML = generateLinkColorHTML(accentColor);

        //Features
        setUpFeaturesView(andDown, backgroundColor, linkColorHTML, foregroundWebView);

        //More Specs button
        setUpMoreSpecsButton(backgroundColor, foreground, (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner));

        //Story Title
        TextView storyTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.story_title);
        storyTitle.setText(this.deal.getStory().getTitle());
        storyTitle.setTextColor(accentColor);

        //Story Body
        setUpStoryBody(andDown, backgroundColor, linkColorHTML, foregroundWebView);

        //Specs Title
        TextView specsTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.specs_title);
        specsTitle.setText(this.deal.getTitle());
        specsTitle.setTextColor(accentColor);

        //Specs
        setUpSpecificationsView(andDown, backgroundColor, linkColorHTML, foregroundWebView);

        //Set up ViewPager
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.photos_view_pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new PhotoPagerAdapter(this, this.deal.getPhotos()));

        //Set up spinner
        setUpSpinner(accentColor, backgroundColor, toolbar);

        //Set up poll title
        TextView pollTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.poll_title);
        pollTitle.setText(this.poll.getTitle());
        pollTitle.setTextColor(accentColor);

        //Set up poll view-forum-topic-in-browser button
        setUpViewForumTopicInBrowserButton(backgroundColor, accentColor);

        //Set up poll
        setUpPoll(foreground, accentColor);

        //Set up video title
        TextView videoTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.video_title);
        videoTitle.setText(this.video.getTitle());
        videoTitle.setTextColor(accentColor);

        //Set up video view-forum-topic-in-browser button
        setUpViewVideoForumTopicInBrowserButton(backgroundColor, accentColor);

        //Set up youtube video
        setUpYoutubeVideo();


    }
```

Log:

```
11-16 18:06:45.879 6507-6507/com.example.meh E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-16 18:06:45.879 6507-6507/com.example.meh E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.meh, PID: 6507
11-16 18:06:45.879 6507-6507/com.example.meh E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setTextColor(int)' on a null object reference
11-16 18:06:45.879 6507-6507/com.example.meh E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.meh.Deal.DealPage$6.onItemSelected(DealPage.java:480)
11-16 18:06:45.879 6507-6507/com.example.meh E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:897)
11-16 18:06:45.879 6507-6507/com.example.meh E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AdapterView.selectionChanged(AdapterView.java:884)
11-16 18:06:45.879 6507-6507/com.example.meh E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AdapterView.checkSelectionChanged(AdapterView.java:1047)
11-16 18:06:45.879 6507-6507/com.example.meh E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AdapterView.handleDataChanged(AdapterView.java:1027)
11-16 18:06:45.879 6507-6507/com.example.meh E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsSpinner.onMeasure(AbsSpinner.java:184)
11-16 18:06:45.879 6507-6507/com.example.meh E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.Spinner.onMeasure(Spinner.java:507)
11-16 18:06:45.879 6507-6507/com.example.meh E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner.onMeasure(AppCompatSpinner.java:410)
11-16 18:06:45.879 6507-6507/com.example.meh E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
11-16 18:06:45.879 6507-6507/com.example.meh E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.measureChildCollapseMargins(Toolbar.java:1225)
11-16 18:06:45.879 6507-6507/com.example.meh E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.onMeasure(Toolbar.java:1333)
11-16 18:06:45.879 6507-6507/com.example.meh E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
11-16 18:06:45.879 6507-6507/com.example.meh E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
11-16 18:06:45.879 6507-6507/com.example.meh E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
11-16 18:06:45.879 6507-6507/com.example.meh E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
11-16 18:06:45.879 6507-6507/com.example.meh E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
11-16 18:06:45.879 6507-6507/com.example.meh E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
11-16 18:06:45.879 6507-6507/com.example.meh E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
11-16 18:06:45.879 6507-6507/com.example.meh E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
11-16 18:06:45.879 6507-6507/com.example.meh E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:124)
11-16 18:06:45.879 6507-6507/com.example.meh E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
11-16 18:06:45.879 6507-6507/com.example.meh E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
11-16 18:06:45.879 6507-6507/com.example.meh E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
11-16 18:06:45.879 6507-6507/com.example.meh E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
11-16 18:06:45.879 6507-6507/com.example.meh E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
11-16 18:06:45.879 6507-6507/com.example.meh E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
11-16 18:06:45.879 6507-6507/com.example.meh E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
11-16 18:06:45.879 6507-6507/com.example.meh E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
11-16 18:06:45.879 6507-6507/com.example.meh E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
11-16 18:06:45.879 6507-6507/com.example.meh E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
11-16 18:06:45.879 6507-6507/com.example.meh E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
11-16 18:06:45.879 6507-6507/com.example.meh E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
11-16 18:06:45.879 6507-6507/com.example.meh E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
11-16 18:06:45.879 6507-6507/com.example.meh E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
11-16 18:06:45.879 6507-6507/com.example.meh E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
11-16 18:06:45.879 6507-6507/com.example.meh E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
11-16 18:06:45.879 6507-6507/com.example.meh E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2560)
11-16 18:06:45.879 6507-6507/com.example.meh E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
11-16 18:06:45.879 6507-6507/com.example.meh E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2001)
11-16 18:06:45.879 6507-6507/com.example.meh E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1767)
11-16 18:06:45.879 6507-6507/com.example.meh E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
11-16 18:06:45.879 6507-6507/com.example.meh E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
11-16 18:06:45.879 6507-6507/com.example.meh E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
11-16 18:06:45.879 6507-6507/com.example.meh E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
11-16 18:06:45.879 6507-6507/com.example.meh E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
11-16 18:06:45.879 6507-6507/com.example.meh E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
11-16 18:06:45.879 6507-6507/com.example.meh E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
11-16 18:06:45.879 6507-6507/com.example.meh E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-16 18:06:45.879 6507-6507/com.example.meh E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
11-16 18:06:45.879 6507-6507/com.example.meh E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
11-16 18:06:45.879 6507-6507/com.example.meh E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-16 18:06:45.879 6507-6507/com.example.meh E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-16 18:06:45.879 6507-6507/com.example.meh E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
11-16 18:06:45.879 6507-6507/com.example.meh E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)f
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
```

`adapterView` is referenced to `Spinner`, not the item you clicked, you should cast the "view" parameter instead.

---

@Rock Lee
After rotated the layout would be refresh, you should resetup the spinner in some callback function like onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig), 
[Android listview disappears after screen rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176179/android-listview-disappears-after-screen-rotation)

Comment: I changed the code to that, and got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

you can use override method onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState(). or to stop calling onCreate() on screen rotation just add this line in your manifest xml android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"

note: your custom class must implements Parcelable example below.

```
@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putParcelable("obj", myClass);
    }

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
 myClass=savedInstanceState.getParcelable("obj"));
}

public class MyClass implements Parcelable {
     private int mData;

 public int describeContents() {
     return 0;
 }

 /** save object in parcel */
 public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
     out.writeInt(mData);
 }

 public static final Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable> CREATOR
         = new Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable>() {
     public MyParcelable createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
         return new MyParcelable(in);
     }

     public MyParcelable[] newArray(int size) {
         return new MyParcelable[size];
     }
 };

 /** recreate object from parcel */
 private MyParcelable(Parcel in) {
     mData = in.readInt();
 }


}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works, but it might still cause other problems according to this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7990543/2423194

Comment: yes he is right . it won't cause any other problem .he meant if you want to handle anything on rotation you should not use this otherwise you can use it . if you want programattically ingnore it use onConfigurationChanged

Comment: I do want to be able to handle things on rotation.